# angularjs ui-bootstrap modal in aside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i have used the example of https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ for the modal and every thing works fine.

with this code, i can open the modal like in the example:

```
$scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: '/resources/views/pages/tasks/edit.html',
        size: size,

    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};
```

for the trigger / button i use this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
```

till here everything works fine.
But now i want to open the model 'aside' (like from the right of my screen)
i found this code:

```
 <button class="btn white active"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#task_modal"
            ui-toggle-class="modal-open-aside"
            ui-target="body" >
 </button>
```

combined whit this div it opens a modal from the right of the screen

```
<div class="modal fade inactive ng-scope " id="task_modal" data-backdrop="false" style="display: none;">
    <div class="right white b-l col-md-8">

    </div>
</div>
```

the only problem is, with the second example, i can't set every option; like keyboard: true and to close the model on backdrop click.

i searched a lot for  a solution, but every site gives examples needing 'more' plugins. and i think the must be a way to fix this without plugins.

can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 2 lines of css will solve your problem

```
  .modal.fade:not(.in) .modal-dialog {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
  }
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ntu4MzQJzA8szLvPKNEc?p=preview)